# How can i active Javascript? Use golang, PhantomJS(agouti)

Tags: go, phantomjs, agouti

How can i active Javascript? Use golang, PhantomJS(agouti).

Hi.

I'm scraping (eg. hulu.com) to use golang and phantomjs(use: https://github.com/sclevine/agouti). 
But, PhantomJS is blocking Javascript.

How can i active Javascipt?

Please tell me.

Example Code

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "github.com/sclevine/agouti"
    "log"
)

// Exclude => Exception handling
func main() {

    driver := agouti.PhantomJS()
    driver.Start();

    page, _ := driver.NewPage()

    page.Navigate("http://www.hulu.jp/24")

    log.Println(page.HTML())
}
```

> go run main.go

Include Text => 'It appears that software on your computer is blocking JavaScript.  To enjoy Hulu.com, you'll need to enable JavaScript in your web browser.  Please configure your security software or browser plugins to allow Hulu.com to load JavaScript.'